# Duplication of specific file format

Tags: python, windows, encoding, notepad++

I have a file format which looks like the following in Notepad ++ if downloaded by a GUI:

```
LF
headerline CR LF
dataline CR LF
...
last dataline LF
LF
headerline CR LF
....
```

and so on

If I run for instance with it through a python script for automatic backup by:

```
output, error = process.communicate()
out = output.splitlines()
with open('test13.txt', 'w') as file:
    for line in out: 
        if line == '\n':
            file.write('\n')
        else: 
            file.write(line)
            file.write ('\n')
```

I get:

```
headerline CR LF
dataline CR LF
dataline CR LF
....
```

How to handle this? It seems like an encoding problem?

If I run with:

```
with io.open('test13.txt', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(output)
```

I get a similar result.

Thanks!

Comment: Please correct your indentation. Also what is `out`supposed to be?

Comment: out is linewise of output ... output is the original of command execution

Comment: Why do you not just write `output` instead of taking `out` and trying to patch the contents?

Comment: with io.open('test13.txt', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(output)
I get a similar result.

Comment: `output` is a single str?  If so, there shouldn't be any *tranformation* writing it to a file. Can you show us a minimal example of `output` that still produces the incorrect result? [mcve]